# how to play a next video automatically when first one stops in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am calling `ChangeVideo()` from an invoke method:

```
InvokeRepeating ("ChangeVideo", 1, TimeToChangeImage);

public void ChangeVideo()
{
    public string[] VedioPaths ={"aa","bb"}

     System.Random random1 = new System.Random();
     PathNO1 = random1.Next (VedioPaths.Length);
     ConfirmPath1 =  VedioPaths[PathNO1];
     Handheld.PlayFullScreenMovie (ConfirmPath1,Color.black,FullScreenMovieControlMode.CancelOnInput);
}
```

I need to play the next video soon after the other finishes. How can I do that? I tried many ways but every time I build I get an error.

I have a string array from which I randomly select a video; once the first video finishes the next one should start playing. I tried using the invoke method but it is giving me an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to load videos in a coroutine:

```
void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(LoadVideos());
}

IEnumerator LoadVideos()
{
    //first vid
    Handheld.PlayFullScreenMovie("vid1.mp4", Color.black, FullScreenMovieControlMode.CancelOnInput);
    yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
    yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();

    //second vid
    Handheld.PlayFullScreenMovie("vid2.mp4", Color.black, FullScreenMovieControlMode.CancelOnInput);
    yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
    yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
}
```

Note that two lines of `yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();` is absolutely required for this method to work. The reason is unknown to me but it won't work otherwise.

Comment: Happy to see this wasn't an isolated issue (had same "weird" behavior few month ago) with the **required** two lines each time. I suspect Unity to use its own kind of `"WaitForEndOfFrame()"` in the way they manage the video player.

Comment: yup it still exists!

Answer (score 2):

Take a look closer to the documentation : https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Handheld.PlayFullScreenMovie.html

> Calling this function will pause Unity during movie playback. When playback finishes Unity will resume

Meaning that, if you want to play 2 videos one after the other, you just have to do :

```
  Handheld.PlayFullScreenMovie (path1,Color.black,FullScreenMovieControlMode.CancelOnInput);
  Handheld.PlayFullScreenMovie (path2,Color.black,FullScreenMovieControlMode.CancelOnInput);
```

Waiting between the two calls may be required though.

Answer (score 0):

There is a very easy way for the lastest VideoPlayer to detect the loop point even if it‘s not looping.

```
public VideoPlayer videoPlayer;
public VideoClip[] videos;
public VideoClip theVideo;
public static int index;
bool isPlaying = true;

void Start()
{
    index = 0;
    videoPlayer = gameObject.GetComponent<VideoPlayer>();
    videoPlayer.loopPointReached += CheckOver;

}
void CheckOver(UnityEngine.Video.VideoPlayer vp)
{
    print("Video Is Over");
    index += 1;
    if (index >= videos.Length)
    {
        index = 0;
    }
    theVideo = videos[index];
    videoPlayer.clip = theVideo;
    videoPlayer.Play();
    isPlaying = true;
}
```